# Generate 6-digit numbers and use letters when numbers exceed 999999

Tags: algorithm, numbers, uniqueidentifier

I am writing a method to generate sequential identifiers of length 6 (fixed length). I want to achieve something similar like the following:

```
 999999 --->  999999
1000000 --->  A00000
3500000 --->  Z00000
3600000 --->  AA0000

and so on.
```

My objective is to generate these numbers monthly for identifiers which means I can regenerate from beginning at the start of each month.

One way to achieve the above would be to check for numbers  > 999999 and then have some conditions based on the length and starting digits and replace accordingly. Is there any efficient way to achieve the above ?

Comment: Your example has 7 characters for things above 999999, not 6

Comment: But, anyway, if you don't need this _exact_ order, `n < 1e7 ? n : (n - 1e7 + parseInt('A00000', 36)).toString(36)` could work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I will see if this can be accommodated.

Comment: Why dont you use hex or base64 ? They are fully implemented in most languages...

Comment: That does seem to be a better approach. Thanks. I guess I will stick to that.

Comment: If "should use regular numbers as high up as possible and only then switch to using letters" isn't a criterium, then indeed something simpler would work well for you. Hex may give you not enough total number space compared to more letters (goes up to 16777215). Base64 would include dashes and slashes and have both lower and upper case which may be a problem. You could in that case use base 36 (0-9, A-Z) just like my example above, but without the special case of n<1000000, so just `n.toString(36)`. (Or if it should be more but unmistakable by humans, take a look at base58 encoding.)

Comment: ...oh I just realized you didn't specify which programming language... I kinda assumed JS for some reason. Sorry. But the general idea can be applied to any language of course.

Comment: Thanks @CherryDT. As you already mentioned, due to constraints of number space, I have decided to modify my implementation and go ahead with base-36. Thanks !